# Creating symlinks with modified path in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, symlink

The idea behind this question is simple but I'm new to batch scripts so the nuances are making it impossible for me. I need to create a set of symlinks to replicate the contents of several source directories, which share a common parent directory, into a target directory. Example:

```
SrcDirParent
    SrcDirA
       FileA
    SrcDirB
       FileB
       SubDir
          FileC
```

Which using symlinks should create:

```
DstDir
    FileA ~
    FileB ~
    SubDir
        FileC ~
```

Using ~ to show a symbolic link. SrcDirParent and DstDir are read as absolute paths from an external file. I don't know what files/folders will be in SrcDirParent, and some of the relevant directories might already exist in DstDir while others do not. If they do exist, I need to merge the symlinks with the existing content.

The barrier that I'm currently hitting is with th filepaths. I planned to use two for loops like this:

```
for /d %%M in (%SRC%\*) do (
    for /r %%F in (%SRC%\%%M\*) do (
        mklink %DST%\%%F %SRC%\%%M\%%F
    )
)
```

But this requires relative filepaths for %%M and %%F and these variables are being filled with absolute paths. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Another issue that I'm anticipating is when the SRC and DST have conflicting filepaths - I don't want to overwrite existing paths with symlinks.

Hope this was the right place to post this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't understand the Dst tree, SubDirA + B missing?

Comment: SrcDir was supposed to be the parent of all source directories. I've edited to make the example a little more clear.

Comment: So you want to eliminate the first subdir level completely, but retain SubSubdirs?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I found a solution:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /d %%M in (%SRC%\*) do (
    pushd %%M
    for /r %%F in (*) do (

        set temp1=%%F
        set temp2=!temp1:%%M=!
        set temp3=!temp2:%%~nxF=!

        if not exist "%DST%!temp3!" (
            mkdir "%DST%!temp3!"
        )

        mklink "%DST%!temp2!" %%F 
    )
    popd %%M
)
```

It uses "pushd" and "popd" to change the directory for the inner loop, "!string:find=replace!" for modifying the directory names, "exist" to check for existing folders before creating a new one, and "EnableDelayedExpansion" to make all the string operations work correctly. Assumes you have SRC and DST variables set already.